# Swedish characters in python error

Tags: python, unicode

I am making a program that uses words with Swedish characters and stores them in a list. I can print Swedish characters before I put them into a list, but after they are put in, they do not appear normally, just a big mess of characters.

Here is my code:

```
# coding=UTF-8 

def get_word(lines, eng=0):
    if eng == 1: #function to get word in english
        word_start = lines[1]

def do_format(word, lang):
    if lang == "sv":
        first_word = word
        second_word = translate(word, lang)
        element = first_word + " - " + second_word
    elif lang == "en":
        first_word = translate(word, lang)
        second_word = word
        element = first_word + " - " + second_word
    return element

def translate(word, lang):
    if lang == "sv":
        return "ENGLISH"
    if lang == "en":
        return "SWEDISH"

translated = []
path = "C:\Users\LK\Desktop\Dropbox\Dokumentai\School\Swedish\V47.txt"

doc = open(path, 'r')           #opens the documen
doc_list = []                   #the variable that will contain list of words
for lines in doc.readlines():   #repeat as many times as there are lines
    if len(lines) > 1:          #ignore empty spaces
        lines = lines.rstrip()  #don't add "\n" at the end
        doc_list.append(lines)  #add to the list
for i in doc_list:
    print i

for i in doc_list:
    if "-" in i:
        if i[0] == "-":
            element = do_format(i[2:], "en")
            translated.append(element)
        else:
            translated.append(i)
    else:
        element = do_format(i, "sv")
        translated.append(element)


print translated
raw_input()
```

I can simplify the problem to a simple code as:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

test_string = "ö"
test_list = ["å"]

print test_string, test_list
```

If I run that, I get this

> > Ã¶ ['\xc3\xa5']

Comment: What do you mean by "mess of characters"? "\xc3\xa5" is it?

Comment: c3+a5 is clearly a reasonable utf8 character

Comment: Have you read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things to notice:

1. The broken character. This seems to happen because your python seems to output UTF-8 but your terminal seems to be configured to some ISO-8859-X mode (hence the two characters). I'd try to use proper unicode strings in Python 2! (always `u"ö"` instead of `"ö"`). And check your locale settings (`locale` command when on linux)
2. The weird string in the list. In Python `print e` will print out `str(e)`. For lists (such as `["å"]`) the implementation of `__str__` is the same as `__repr__`. And since `repr(some_list)` will call `repr` on any of the elements contained in the list, you end up with the string you see.

Example for `repr(string)`:

```
>>> print u"ö"
ö
>>> print repr(u"ö")
u'\xf6'
>>> print repr("ö")
'\xc3\xb6'
```

Comment: I'm no windows user but apparently it's `import sys; sys.stdout.encoding` when running the Python interpreter from the command line. For me under Linux it outputs `UTF-8` which is correct :-)

Comment: Yeah, CP850 is quite similar to ISO-8859-1 if I remember correctly. This page should explain it: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Answer (score 1):

If you print list then it can be print as some structure. You should convert it to string for example by using `join()` string method. With your test code it may looks like:

```
print test_string, test_list
print('%s, %s, %s' % (test_string, test_list[0], ','.join(test_list)))
```

And output:

```
ö ['\xc3\xa5']
ö, å, å
```

I think in your main program you can:

```
print('%s' % (', '.join(translated)))
```

Comment: Do not print list. Print item like `test_list[0]`, or whole list like: `','.join(test_list)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) module to specify encoding of the read bytes.

```
import codecs

doc = codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')           #opens the document
```

Files opened with [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) will give you unicode string after decoding the raw bytes with specified encoding.

In you code, prefix your string literals with `u`, to make them unicode string.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

test_string = u"ö"
test_list = [u"å"]

print test_string, test_list[0]
```